# Is there a formula to calculate the sum of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given that "*r*" is a constant real number, I have a series that goes like this:

$$
r^1 + r^2 + r^3 ...
$$

Is there a formula that can tell the sum of the first *n* elements? So basically a formula for calculating this sum:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} r^k
$$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is a geometric series, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html for how to compute the sum.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I had no idea it was called that. I'll check it out then :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1185259

Answer (score 1):

This is the sum of a geometric series, with starting term $r$ and common ratio of $r$ as well.

Now, the general sum of the this series is:

$$S = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

A special case is when $|r| < 1$:

$$S = \frac{1}{1-r}$$

Comment: What's the point of posting this for the $N$th time?

Comment: To assist users who can't perform a simple google search

Comment: They can be assisted by marking their question as a duplicate of a canonical question, better than by a hurried two-line answer.

Comment: I tried to google it, but since I had no idea that this was called a geometric series, I couldn't really find anything. Now that I know, I can find the answer myself of course. I just didn't know it was called that. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @NormalHuman you see the OPs answer.

Comment: My point stands: they can be assisted by marking their question as a duplicate of a canonical question, better than by a hurried two-line answer.

Comment: @NormalHuman Even though I appreciate the answer, I agree with that